# JPA @Version Version - increases in the database, but gives an update to the record with a smaller version

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, version

I have entity Person with @Version field

When updating in the database, the version increases, everything is ok, but it also allows you to write with a smaller version than this etity in the database has. How so? The version should be automatically controlled, but when I submit an entity with a lower version, the data in the database is updated and the version is increased by 1. Why does it allow me to update the record with the old version?

```
@Entity
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class Person {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    private Long id;

    @Column(name="firstname")
    private String firstname;

    @Column(name="age")
    private int age;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "optlock" )
    private Long version;
```

service

```
    public  void updatePerson(Person person){
        Person one = personRepository.getPersonById(person.getId());
        one.setFirstname(person.getFirstname());
        one.setAge(person.getAge());
        one.setVersion(person.getVersion());
        personRepository.save(one);
    }
```

i send JSON to my controller

```
{
    "id": 1,
    "firstname": "Thomas",
    "age": 37,
    "version": 2
}
```

but in the database I have one record with id = 1 with version 3
And the update is successful. The version is not controlled, the exception is not thrown.
After the update, the version becomes = 4

Why?

Comment: Generally, your version field should not have a setter at all; it's supposed to be automatically managed.

Comment: chrylis -cautiouslyoptimistic Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hibernate per the JPA Spec does not allow to set manually a version of a managed entity.

See(section 2.2.1.2 of the hibernate docs here : https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html

If you want to throw an optimistic lock if the version is lower than expected, you could do:

```java
public  void updatePerson(Person person){
       // ensure the person you trying to update exists (eg: existsById )
        personRepository.save(person);
    }
```

if the person version attribute is lower than the one in DB, hibernate will raise an optimistic lock exception.